# in python with matplotlib, when doing a histogram, how is it determining the start and end point of each bin?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, visualization, data-science

in python with matplotlib, when doing a histogram, how is it determining the start and end point of each bin?

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1k00d1OhIUwcBl1zetXtKXBVvuNS8FYpL

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,5]

plt.hist(x, bins=5)
```

how is it calcuating the start and end point of each bin?
why does the first bin start at 1, but the last bin start at around 4.25?
why does one of the bins end at about 3.4?

[image]

Comment: trying this basic guide on how to plot histograms in python https://datatofish.com/plot-histogram-python/

Comment: The range between the minimum and maximum data is divided by the number of bins; here [1,5] is divided into 5 bins, so each bin is (5-1)/5 = 0.8 wide.